# Find the object that contains title1-2

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, array

I use jQuery and `underscore.js`, I have `title1-2` and I would like to have the action corresponding.

```
this.items = {
    menuItems: [
        { title: 'title1',
            data: [
                { title: 'title1-1',
                    action: 'action1-1'
                },
                { title: 'title1-2',
                    action: 'action1-2'
                }
                ]
        },
        { title: 'title2',
            data: [
                { title: 'title2-1',
                    action: 'action2-1'
                },
                { title: 'title2-2',
                    action: 'action2-2'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

Currently, I have the following code to do this:

```
var item = _.find(_.flatten(_.pluck(this.items.menuItems, 'data')), function (item) { return item.title === 'title1-2'; });
console.log(item.action);
```

Is there a better way to find it?

Comment: So I assume that you want to find the object that contains title1-2?

Comment: exactly, thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the only improvement I think you can make is that you use the chaining sugar, looks a lot better:

```
var item = _.chain(items.menuItems)
  .pluck('data')
  .flatten()
  .find(function(a){
    return a.title === 'title1-2'
  })
  .value()
```